# App not installing in emulator after upgrading to android studio chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So pushing the run app button in android studio compiles the app. But it does not install the compiled app into emulator. App is compiled successfully .

```
> Task :app:packageGoogleDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createGoogleDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleGoogleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 16s 41 actionable tasks: 41 up-to-date
```

it just stop here. Adb is working fine. i can see the emulator log in logcat.

i have 2 build flavour. Both are the same. Compiles but not installing.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.5.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the culprit.. looking at android studio logs.. Its the HMS toolkit.. if you guys have that installed... just disable the plugin until huawei fix it.. the run button will work properly..

````
2022-05-10 16:52:43,924 [  10645]  ERROR - e.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-05-10 16:52:43,924 [  10645]  ERROR - e.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader - OS: Mac OS X 
2022-05-10 16:52:43,924 [  10645]  ERROR - e.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader - Plugin to blame: HMS Toolkit version: 6.3.0.3003.AF 
2022-05-10 16:52:43,926 [  10647]  ERROR - e.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader - Calling `ClassLoader#getResource` with leading slash doesn't work; strip 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: /icons/pushkit/add_light.png [Plugin: com.huawei.deveco.hms]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.doFindResource(PluginClassLoader.java:492)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(PluginClassLoader.java:462)
    at com.huawei.kits.pushkit.utils.PushIconUtils.load(PushIconUtils.java:93)
    at com.huawei.kits.pushkit.utils.PushIconUtils.<clinit>(PushIconUtils.java:62)
    at com.huawei.kits.pushkit.ui.SampleMessagePanel.initPanel(SampleMessagePanel.java:87)
    at com.huawei.kits.pushkit.ui.SampleMessagePanel.<init>(SampleMessagePanel.java:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.resloader.JarLoader.createObject(JarLoader.java:130)
    at com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module.lambda$createModuleView$0(Module.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.forEach(TreeMap.java:1002)
    at com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module.createModuleView(Module.java:239)
    at com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Application.initAllModuleViews(Application.java:287)
    at com.huawei.hms.core.component.InitProjectComponent.<init>(InitProjectComponent.java:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:877)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:60)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectExImpl.init(ProjectExImpl.kt:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:339)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.access$prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$doOpenAsync$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$doOpenAsync$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressRunner$1.apply(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressRunner$1.apply(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)```
````

Comment: Thanks!!! i didnt see the log.... i learned from you!!

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating cache worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Did that multiple times.. doesnt work.. manually delete build folder also doesnt work

Comment: Ran into this again on an emulator and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

When I was facing the same issue, I raised a ticket to the Google team, they said Please uninstall the HMS ToolKit plugin, because It was causing issues.

you can check here.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232107670

Answer (score 0):

1. delete all build folders
2. invalidate caches and restart
3. create a new `API31` emulator and run 'app'

these steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to cold boot the emulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to look at my Event Log.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At least for me the culprit was HMS toolkit. I am not sure why it showed that the build was successful but it did not install.

- Invalidate caches and restart.
- Android Studio shows a small popup on the bottom right that there is
  a problem with HMS toolkit. Click that and disable HMS toolkit.

It started working after that.

Answer (score 0):

The project builds successfully only the app is not installed on the emulator. This is happening after upgrading Android Studio. Currently, I am dragging apk file from ProjectName/app/build/output/apk/dev/debug/devDebug.apk, and its working for me